# action in commandButton is not called in when using oncomplete

Tags: jsf, richfaces

There are similar questions elsewhere on stackoverflow as well, but unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer that I have been looking for.

I am new to JSF. I am required to display two popupPanels when deleting an item that is authorized and just one when it is not.

Problem arises when I use onclick to call the popupPanel, the action in the first popupPanel is called, but the second popupPanel is not rendered(?). I fixed that by changing onclick to oncomplete. However that leads to another problem: items that are authorized are deleted normally, but the ones that are not authorized cause problems (the action is not called at all). I am pasting the code below.

I have a dataTable in which one column is for deleting:

```
<rich:column innerId="c7">
    <a4j:commandLink execute="@this"
        onclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeleteModalPanel')}.show();"
        render="confirmDeleteModalPanel" >
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedItem}" value="#{item}" />
            <h:graphicImage url="/img/delete.png"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
</rich:column>
```

This calls this popupPanel:

```
<rich:popupPanel modal="true" id="confirmDeleteModalPanel">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{item.isAuthorised()}">
                <a4j:commandButton value="#{messages['button.yes']}"
                          onclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeleteModalPanel')}.hide(); #{rich:component('doubleConfirmDeleteModalPanel')}.show(); "
                          render="doubleConfirmDeleteModalPanel" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!item.isAuthorised()}">
                 <a4j:commandButton value="#{messages['button.yes']}"
                                   action="#{item.delete()}"
                                onclick="#{rich:component('confirmDeleteModalPanel')}.hide()" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Which subsequently calls another one as the one above it. For brevity, I haven't posted the other popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the error (not so firm with JSF any more), but you might want to try to use `action="#{item.delete}"` instead of `action="#{item.delete()}"`.  It could be the case that the action that is called is the *result* of the `item.delete()` call, and not the `item.delete` function.

Example:
Suppose `item.delete()` returns "`aResult`".

With `action="#{item.delete()}"`, when the user clicks the button, the action "`aResult`" is called, which probably does not exist.

With `action="#{item.delete}"`, when the user clicks the button, the action "`#{item.delete}`" is called, i.e., the `delete` method on the bean named `item`, which is what you were expecting.

Comment: Hmm :(  what happens if you remove the `onclick`?  Could be the case that the onclick overwrites the `action` action.